# Erro ao tentar gerar gráfico do PHPlot em Zend framework

Tags: php, zend

Estou tentando usar o phplot pra plotar um gráfico dentro de uma aplicação feita em Zend framework, mas resulta em erro. É fácil de plotar com o phplot, estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
// view helper que desenha o grafico
// a helper ja ta configurada no module.config
// ShowGraph.php

<?php

namespace Admin\View\Helper;

use Zend\Phplot\PHPlot;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class ShowGraph extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function __invoke($data)
    {

       $plot = new PHPlot(500 , 350); 
       $title = "Consulta de carros";
       $plot->SetTitle($title);
       $plot->SetPlotType("bars");
       $plot->SetDataType("text-data");
       $plot->SetDataValues($data);
       $plot->SetXTickPos('none');
       $plot->SetXLabel("Fonte: GTI Submit");
       $plot->SetXLabelFontSize(2);
       $plot->SetAxisFontSize(2);

       $plot->SetDataValueLabelColor('red');
       $plot->SetYDataLabelPos('plotin');
       return $plot->DrawGraph();
    }
}

?>

// Chamo aqui no index a helper passando array $data
// index.phtml

<img src="<?php echo $this->showGraph($data); ?>" />
```

Entretanto está retornando o seguinte erro:

```
Fatal error: DrawGraph(): No image resource allocated
```

Comment: Poderia colocar a parte do código que faz o plot?

Comment: Aqui esta um dos código que fiz, pois tentei de varias formas adaptar dentro do Zend Framework. https://ghostbin.com/paste/tdbah